# Not aligned with employer's current strategy - need advice

Tags: software-industry, career-development, developer, software, software-development

I am currently a mobile developer. Recently i've noticed a trend in the company i'm working at: the management's **enforcement** of mobile application development using hybrid technology (the **very** proprietary sort).

Although I believe that applications built using these types of  hybrid technologies (HTML/CSS/JS) will get a bigger market share in the future, I feel that the timing is not right.

I'd like keep developing myself as an IOS/Android developer because I find it much more enjoyable than HTML/CSS/JS.

I fear that if keep working here I might risk not having transferable skills if need/opportunity to work somewhere else arises.

I am considering actively looking another company with its interests in technology approaches more in sync with mine.

Any advice?

More info about me:

- Recent graduate in my twenties
- This is my first job and i've at it for about 9 months
- The company I work for is medium/big size (300/400) but working under the shadow of an industry giant.

Comment: hello, consider [edit]ing the question to make it better fit site topics laid out in [help/on-topic]. In particular, [this guidance](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2695) may help to learn what is expected of questions here. Good luck!

Comment: haha, I can't stress my question to you enough. How in the world are HTML/CSS/JS  skills NOT transferable?

Comment: HTML/CSS/JS enclosed in one very proprietary framework

Comment: @furian the only thing I can think of responding with is: so?

Comment: You expect hybrid applications to grow in the future, and at the same time, you're worried that web technologies won't be a viable skill set? Which one is it? It sounds like you're just trying to vent. You like developing native apps. That's fine (so do I). But don't fool yourself into thinking that web technologies are not a highly sought after skill set, now and in the future.

Answer (score 6):

First off, HTML/CSS/JS skills, regardless of how proprietary the framework those languages are used, are almost always transferable to any company. You may not be using the same framework at a different company, but you'll already have a leg up over the people who don't understand how HTML/CSS/JS actually works.

Honestly, though, when it comes to self-marketing your programming skills, your ability to understand programming fundamentals as well as your problem-solving skills matter considerably more than your knowledge of specific languages. In other words, once you understand one language, it's very easy to pick up another, especially if you already know an OOP language and a web development language.

However, if you aren't liking the job because you wanted to focus on more native Obj-C or Java programming to go with iOS and Android, then I would find a job that focuses on something like speedy applications. Keep in mind, though, that as companies change over time, their focus and coding language choice could change over time as well.

Answer (score 3):

You have to understand, COMPANY hired YOU, and to put it in the simplest terms, you have some to no influence on the approach company take on developing the software. Your job is to be a great developer, if you can't fulfill the role, they might replace you.

There are 3 ways you can take:

1. Do what you are told to do with suggestions from your end that ALIGN with the company's approach.
2. Find a new company that aligns with your interests - but again, be careful there as they can change the direction abruptly in future - you have to accept that you are a developer, not product owner.
3. Create your own product and make money yourself - this way you are the one sailing the boat ;)

I look at it this way: I am a professional with extensive development skill set. I do offer my vision and share experience, introduce improvements and try to change things when appropriate - but the final decision is after the product owner, and I am cool with that - they pay me for that :)

In general though, I try to stick to open minded bosses who do take advantage of healthy discussion with employees.